# How can I get a list of supported Ubuntu releases from the CLI?

Tags: command-line, packaging

What's the simplest way to get codenames of currently supported Ubuntu releases for use in deb packaging? Like `utopic trusty precise lucid` for today.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `distro-info`:

```
$ distro-info --supported
lucid
precise
trusty
utopic
vivid
```

You may need to `sudo apt-get install distro-info` first. The tool takes its information from the package `distro-info-data`, which is updated in all supported releases when release data changes.

Comment: How did `vivid` get in there?

Comment: Looks like `distro-info` defines "supported" as "created but not EOL", which includes Vivid. You could use `distro-info --devel` to get the name of the development release and then exclude it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the current release has any idea about the names of the previous releases. You will need to get that information online.

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases is a good candidate

This will do the job until they reformat that page:

`wget -q https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases -O -  | sed -n -l 999 /Current/,/Future/l  | grep '^  <td style="background-color: #f1f1dd"><p class="line891">' | grep -v http | grep -v /ReleaseNotes | cut -d ">" -f 4 | cut -d "<" -f 1 | sort | uniq | cut -d " " -f 1 | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]'`

Output:

```
lucid
precise
trusty
utopic
```

Explanation:

- wget retrieves the web page with the releases,
- sed cuts the lines between Current and Future
- 3 * grep filters out some unwanted table cells
- 2 * cut takes only the cell with the code name (2 words - like "Trusty Tahr", etc)
- sort and uniq removes the duplicates
- the next cut gives you the firs word only (the adjective)
- tr makes it lowercase

Comment: `distro-info --supported` is simple :)